# Static memory overwriting (machine code) on runtime with c++

Tags: c++, assembly

I want to modify a single-player game **A** which will be done with application **B**. When application **B** is launched it finds the game **A** process and overwrites some assembly code. Without launched application **B** game should be modified. In short, I want to be able to edit the machine code of any application, as it is possible in cheat engine, in application runtime

OS I am working on is Windows 10 x64. Game A is written in assembly x86.

I know where the code is located **A.exe + pointer**, and the length of the code **5 bytes**

The code I have currently does not work, because of an exception "Access violation reading location"

Writing to address of assembly code

```cpp
DWORD oldPermissions;
BYTE* whereToWrite = (BYTE*) aExeBaseAddress + pointer;
BYTE* replacementCode = {0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90}; // Nop's in assembly, this is just example value
VirtualProtect(whereToWrite, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldPermissions);
memcpy(whereToWrite, replacementCode, 5); // This place throws exception, because I do not have permissions
VirtualProtect(whereToWrite, 5, oldPermissions, &oldPermissions);
```

Reading from address of assembly code

```cpp
DWORD oldPermissions;
BYTE* fromWhereToRead = (BYTE*) aExeBaseAddress + pointer;
BYTE* whereToWrite = new BYTE[5];
VirtualProtect(fromWhereToRead, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldPermissions);
memcpy(whereToWrite, fromWhereToRead, 5); // This place throws exception, because I do not have permissions
VirtualProtect(fromWhereToRead, 5, oldPermissions, &oldPermissions);
```

The Assembly code that I am trying to overwrite is a function call. I would like the game **A** to call a function on application **B**. So even if I am able to get byte code to be overwritten, I still need a way how to get a pointer to a function on application **B**, turn it into bytecode for application **A** to call

Is it even possible, what I am trying to achieve?
Thanks for suggestions and help

Comment: No. If you want to add code to a process you need to inject a dll that hosts it.

Comment: Too general question, answer depends on OS and hardware and likely would involve soem assembler and PEXE loader procedure knowledge. essentially you have to look on sources\periodicals related to hacking, yes it's in general case is possible unless platform designed to prevent it (or prevent it in most cases). Essentially is a security breach, operation system and antiviral software would catch your hand.

Comment: For the read/write: [Can one process overwrite the memory of another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4893504/555045) The callback is basically not going to happen with this setup, if you use DLL injection then sure (and in that case you also won't need that special way of reading and writing across process boundaries)

Comment: if target process is _your_ program , you actually can export a  function (similar to how .dll do export), there is a way to hook two processes together..but question, why to do so aside from debugging purposes?

Comment: Assembly code is source code (i.e. text), not machine code. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because too broad